# Evaluation of a limit with integral

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

Is this limit
$$\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\,\,\varepsilon\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\frac{e^{-\varepsilon|x|}}{|x|^2(1+|x|^2)^s}$$
with $s>\frac{1}{2}$, zero?.

The limit of a product is the product of limit, so I evaluate
$$\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\,\,\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\frac{e^{-\varepsilon|x|}}{|x|^2(1+|x|^2)^s}$$.
With the theorem of dominated convergence the last limit equals
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\frac{1}{|x|^2(1+|x|^2)^s}=4\pi\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{(1+r^2)^s}=C<\infty$$
(I have used the fact that $s>\frac{1}{2}$)

Using the product rule I have the result.
Have I made some mistake?

Answer (score 1):

What you did is correct. The only thing you have to take care is that *in general*, dominated convergence theorem applies for sequences. Here there is no problem since the convergence is monotonic.

Comment: Do you really need monotonicity to justify this? I mean, if $I(\epsilon)$ denotes the integral, then $\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0^+}I(\epsilon)=I$ if and only if $I(\epsilon_n)$ tends to $I$ for every sequence $\epsilon_n$ tending to $0^+$.

Comment: I agree with @Julien.

Comment: @julien I agree monotonicity is not needed (anyway I think the argument of going back to sequences should be mentioned).

Comment: Sure. I also always go back to sequences in such a situation.

Comment: Going back to sequences is a standard procedure in cases like this; for this reason I didn't mention it. But you have reason, maybe if I mentioned iit my reasoning was clearer.